# A sufficient condition for almost sure convergence.

Tags: probability-limit-theorems, almost-everywhere

I have been working on the following problem.

> **Prove that** if a sequence $X_n$ of random variables satisfies 
>   $$\lim_{n,m\rightarrow \infty}P\left\{ \sup_{m<k\leq n} |X_k-X_m|\geq \delta  \right\}=0 \hspace{1cm}\forall \delta>0$$
>   then there is a limiting random variable $X$ such that $X_n \xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{a.s}X$.

First of all, this question has been asked in "[From Cauchy in Measure to Almost Sure Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1437339/523306)" but the answer is not complete. Especially, it is not clear where he used the sup in the condition.

**Opinion**

At first glance, it seems right to start from noting that $X_n$ is Cauchy so there is a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ which is convergent a.s. to a random variable $X$. Then I was trying to use the argument given in the answer of the question linked above by showing that $$P\left\{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X_n-X|>\lambda  \right\}=0$$  for any $\lambda >0$. And note that

$$P\left\{\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X_n-X|>\lambda  \right\}= P\left\{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{n<k}|X_k-X|>\lambda  \right\}$$
But seems there is no relation to the given condition and I don't know how to get further.

I thank in advance for any help!